# Select-String -Pattern Wildcard Match

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a number of `.ps1` scripts in a folder, example file content shown below:

```
file1.ps1
# Do stuff
Get-Acl -Path HKLM:\

file2.ps1
# Do stuff
Get-ADUser -Identity TestUser
```

Using the command `Select-String` I want to find .ps1 scripts with AD cmdlets only, e.g. `Get-ADUser`, `Get-ADGroup` etc.. Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyScripts | Select-String -Pattern "Get-AD*"
```

This returns file1.ps1 and file2.ps1, expected output is file2.ps1 **only**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `Get-AD*` to `Get-AD\w+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select-String` uses regular expressions, not wildcard patterns, and in that context `*` means "0 or more of the previous element" - so it's looking for the literal string `Get-A` followed by 0 or more `D`'s - and `Get-Acl` does indeed satisfy this constraint.

To describe a substring starting with `Get-AD` followed by some more letters, you can do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyScripts | Select-String -Pattern "Get-AD\p{L}+"
```

`\p{L}` descibes any *letter*, `+` means "1 or more of the previous element", so `Get-AD` followed by 1 or more letters.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to match last 10 lines with Select-String -Pattern.
so I used a space to match or you can use . this worked for me.

```
select-string $CurrentLog -pattern " " | Select-Object -last 12
```